# C# threaded procedure call with passed in parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, procedure

A noob thread question... I wish to call the sendSMS procedure via a new thread but face the issue of not being able to pass parameters in. Short of using a global variable that tracks the values of user1Mobile and messageContents, what is the basic technique when addressing this problem? I've read into a few articles but I'm convinced they are overkill.

Usually I would launch via:

```
ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(speakTextNewThread);
            Thread thread = new Thread(sendSMS);
            thread.Start();
```

Called from anywhere within my app right now and what I wish to make threadable:

```
sendSMS(Settings1.Default.user1Mobile, messageContents)
```

The procedure doing the sending:

```
private string sendSMS(string phoneNumber, string messageToSend)
    {
        try
        {
            API api = new API(Settings1.Default.clockworkAPIKey);

            SMS sms = new SMS
            {
                To = phoneNumber,
                Message = messageToSend
            };

            SMSResult result = api.Send(sms);

            if (result.Success)
                return "Sent\nID: " + result.ID;                
            else
                return "Error: " + result.ErrorMessage;
        }
        catch (APIException ex)
        {
            // You'll get an API exception for errors 
            // such as wrong key
            return "API Exception: " + ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest wat would be:

```
new Thread(() => sendSMS(Settings1.Default.user1Mobile, messageContents)).Start();
```

or

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Settings1.Default.user1Mobile, messageContents));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BackgroundWorker`. Basically this means that you start up another thread and feed it with your code and parameters; the background worker will do the work on its own thread and notify the main thread when it is finished.

Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Thanks, definitely a topic worth exploring

Answer (score 0):

see below for starting your own thread:

```
string retMsg
var t = new Thread(() => retMsg = sendSMS(Settings1.Default.user1Mobile, messageContents));
t.Start();
```

I added retMsg if you want to do something with the return value

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the retMsg thing, as it happens I do no need a return value.

Comment: I declared string retMsg = "something"; but it didn't update after running the next 2 lines. The sendSMS event however ran correctly.

Comment: Aaah, I see what's happening. The threaded call doesn't return the value in time.

Comment: yes you need to add t.Join() to wait for the thread to finish

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. As your passing more than one parameter you require a delegate().

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
{
    sendSMS(phoneNumber,message);
});
thread.Start();
```

You will also need to pass the parameters as objects and convert to string once captured by your method :-

```
private string sendSMS(object phoneNumber, object messageToSend)
{
  string pnumber = (string)phoneNumber;
  string msg = (string)messageToSend;

   // DO REST OF WORK HERE.
}
```